# Blinking cursor as default in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cursor, blink, becomefirstresponder

How can I make cursor blink when the view is opened without touching anywhere. I am currently using becomeFirstResponder() My text field becomes really first responder but when the view is opened, blink does not blink. Why?

My code is here.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let resultTextField: UITextField = {
        var myField = UITextField()
        myField.textColor = .blue
        myField.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 36)
        myField.textAlignment = .right
        myField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        return myField
    }()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(resultTextField)
        resultTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        resultTextField.inputView = UIView()
    }
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        let myWidth = self.view.frame.width
        let myHeight = self.view.frame.height
        resultTextField.frame = CGRect(x: (myWidth - (myWidth / 1.15))/2,
                                       y: myHeight / 7.5,
                                       width: myWidth / 1.15,
                                       height: myHeight / 15)
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, try to call becomeFirstResponder method in viewDidAppear instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Luca, try calling becomeFirstResponder in **viewDidAppear** or in your layoutSubviews function. `viewDidLoad()`only means that your UIViewController has been loaded to memory but is not displayed yet. Easy way to verify this is implementing a subclass from UITextField and override the `caretRect` which returns the cursor's frame. Set a breakpoint and test the code ...

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {
   override func caretRect(for position: UITextPosition) -> CGRect {
      /// set a breakpoint and you will notice that it's not called with the viewDidLoad() of your UIViewController 
      return super.caretRect(for: position)
   }
}
```